# Click hyperlink on WebView launch other browser app

Tags: android, webview

I use below code to load URLPath in WebView:

```
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    String myURL = URLPath;
    WebSettings websettings = webView.getSettings();  
    websettings.setSupportZoom(true);  
    websettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);   
    websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());  
    webView.loadUrl(myURL);
```

The url page contain hyperlink.
I want to launch other browser app(such as chrome) while click hyperlink.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
  if(url.equals("http:\\your.url")
      view.loadUrl(url);
  else
  // Do something here to open link in google chrome or some external browser
  return true;
}
});
```